# PHP Foreach Arrays and objects

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I have an array of objects; running `print_r()` returns the output below;

```php
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sm_id] => 1
            [c_id] => 1
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sm_id] => 1
            [c_id] => 2
        )
)
```

How to loop through the result and access the student class objects?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use

```
//$arr should be array as you mentioned as below
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
  echo $value->sm_id;
}
```

OR

```
//$arr should be array as you mentioned as below
foreach($arr as $value){
  echo $value->sm_id;
}
```

Comment: Note that the `$key=>` part is not needed

Comment: But it's recommended to include the `$key => ` part. According to this benchmark, the loop is twice as fast, when you *include* the $key part: http://www.phpbench.com/

Answer (score 7):

Looping over arrays and objects is a pretty common task, and it's good that you're wanting to learn how to do it. Generally speaking you can do a [`foreach` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) which cycles over each member, assigning it a new temporary name, and then lets you handle that particular member via that name:

```
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    echo $item->sm_id;
}
```

In this example each of our values in the `$arr` will be accessed in order as `$item`. So we can print our values directly off of that. We could also include the index if we wanted:

```
foreach ($arr as $index => $item) {
    echo "Item at index {$index} has sm_id value {$item->sm_id}";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your `sm_id` and `c_id` properties are public, you can access them by using a `foreach` on the array:

```
$array = array(/* objects in an array here */);
foreach ($array as $obj) {
    echo $obj->sm_id . '<br />' . $obj->c_id . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Recursive traverse object or array with array or objects elements:

```
function traverse(&$objOrArray)
{
    foreach ($objOrArray as $key => &$value)
    {
        if (is_array($value) || is_object($value))
        {
            traverse($value);
        }
        else
        {
            // DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
}
```