# How to use foreach value for db coumn name as variable in Codeigniter view file

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a view file where I need to echo db column values using foreach method.

I have column e.g. `column_a, column_b, column_c....`

I am able to get values if I use `<?= $variable_1->column_a; ?>`

But I need to echo them like `<?= $variable_1->column_.$variable_2; ?>`

If I use it the second way, gives error

> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$column_

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707836/php-foreach-arrays-and-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<?php $colname = "column_{$variable_2}"; ?>
<?= $variable_1->{$colname}; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Alan Horrocks.. It still says, `UNDEFINED column_{$column}`

Comment: Glad you got it working :) Note that using double-quotes was important in my answer - if you use single quotes php won't interpret the value of $column.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Alan Horrocks as he showed me the right direction:

I worked by doing

`<?php $column = $session_data['default']; ?>
    <?php $colname = 'column_'.$column; ?>
    <?= $listing->$colname; ?>`